# excellent though cookbooks are as resources for the programmer - I can't understand this phrase

Tags: grammar

> A pattern describes a problem in software design and provides the kernel of a solution. “Solution” here does not mean the kind of cut-and-paste code that you might find in a cookbook (**excellent though cookbooks are as resources for the programmer**). Instead, a design pattern describes an approach that can be taken to solve a problem.

I don't quite get what that phrase in parentheses means.

Comment: I think a simple shift would make it make sense, *(cookbooks are excellent though, as resources for the programmer)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"even though cookbooks are excellent as resources for the programmer"

The clarification the author is making is that he does not mean to disparage cookbooks, and his larger sentence is not meant as any sort of criticism, merely a differentiation.